# check time in bat file and continue with action?

Tags: batch-file, time

I'm trying to run another bat file using this one at a certain time but whenever I try, it runs it no matter what.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

ping www.google.com

pause

start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://inbox.google.com"

set tm=time

set hh=!tm:~0,2!
set mm=!tm:~3,2!
if !hh! lss 19 (
    goto :done
)
if !hh! equ 19 (
    if !mm! lss 45 (
        goto :done
    )
)
start "" "C:\Users\AdminNUS\Desktop\Dimmer.bat"
:done
endlocal
```

Comment: One suggestion: if your environment supports this, switch to windows scripting host or powershell, both may be already installed on the computers you use. It is way easier to do such things with something more of "high level language" than bitching batches can offer. People often forget about wsh and they would be much easier off when using that.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here: `set tm=time` This line stores the string `time` in the variable `%tm%`. So `set hh=!tm:~0,2!` stores `ti` in `%hh%` and so on. To fix this you simply have to surround `time` with `%%`:

```
set tm=%time%
```

This should be it.

Comment: Yes. User [MC ND](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) indicated the same thing two hours ago...